# How to literally take the wing off a single engine Beechcraft-style airplane?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

First off I do not want to do any kind of maintenance. I was driving past an auto junk yard and saw they have half of a low wing, maybe a Beechcraft, airplane and I would like to try and buy the wing for a table or some type of project. I would like to know what kind of tools required to do such a task other than a sawzall!

Comment: Taking a wing off can be difficult if you don't know what you are getting into. There are cables, fuel lines, electrical, etc in the wing, one of which can cause a fire. The best thing to do if you really want this is to find an A&P and pay them a couple hundred bucks to take it off.

Answer (score 4):

A normal collection of combination wrenches and sockets, in inches, plus pliers, wire cutters etc, the ole' help along hammer, small bolt cutters for cutting control cable, etc. should do the trick.  Maybe sawhorses to rest the fuselage and wing on.  If the wings are individually removable, they'll be attached with two big bolts or two rows of smaller bolts, just inside the cabin under the seats, and a singe bolt at the back on each side.

The main thing to take care with is there'll be a hydraulic line running out the wing root to the landing gear leg with red hydraulic fluid (similar to ATF fluid) in it for that side's brake, so you should disconnect at each end and drain the brake line first, and there is probably a fuel tank so you need to make sure that is drained and be ready to catch fuel when you disconnect the fuel line connection at the fuselage.   If it's been sitting there for years the fuel is probably all gone but best be ready just in case.  Bring along a fire extinguisher while you're at it.

It's not much different than cutting up a car except the metal is easier to hack at if you want to take the sawzall to it.

Comment: Exactly the info I was looking for, Thank you John K and Ron Beyer!! I was a body man for about 9 years so the work itself doesn't scare me I wasn't sure if there were any specialty tools required. Once again thank you both!

Comment: @CharlesMGorman as you're not looking to use it as an aircraft part, even if special tools were normally needed you could just take a hacksaw or or cutting tool if need be.